# How to set a system-wide gtk theme in NixOS?

Tags: gtk, nixos, accessibility

Is there a way to set system-wide default GTK theme to "HighContrast" in the same manner, one can set font DPI on a system level?

Here is the snippet I use for the font DPI:

```
  fonts = {
    fontconfig = {
      dpi = 160;
    };
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to write config files into "/etc/xdg" (not "/etc").
`gtk-2.0` and `gtk-3.0` are directories in the same directory as `configuration.nix`:

```
  environment.etc = {
    "xdg/gtk-2.0".source =  ./gtk-2.0;
    "xdg/gtk-3.0".source =  ./gtk-3.0;
  };
```